# Problem updating a variable inside a method | JAVA

Tags: java

I'm having an issue updating an object inside a method

```
public Admin getAdminByName(String name) throws InexistentUserException {

        Admin currentAdmin = null;
        for (Admin admin : adminList){
            if (admin.getUserName().equals(name)){
                currentAdmin = admin; //This update is still null
            }
            else { throw new InexistentUserException("The admin does not exist");}
        }
        return currentAdmin;
    }
```

This code returns null always. I don't need to create a new object Admin, as I should create more than the already existing ones, I just need to locate one by its name

Comment: This method can only return null if `adminList` is empty.

Comment: Why not just `return admin;` instead of setting the `currentAdmin` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing in the wrong place. Right now your code iterates over the list and as soon as it doesn't find a match, it throws the exception.

Ideally what you want to do is search until you find a match and then stop and return that match.

After the for loop, you'd want an if statement that checks whether your currentAdmin is null. If it is then you'd throw a NoAdminExceptionFound or something along those lines.

```
package eu.webfarmr;

public class Admin {
    private String username;
    private final static Admin[] adminList = new Admin[] {new Admin("Alice"), new Admin("Bob"), new Admin("Carol") };
    
    public static Admin getAdminByName(String name) throws InexistentUserException {

        Admin currentAdmin = null;
        for (Admin admin : adminList){
            if (admin.getUserName().equals(name)){
                currentAdmin = admin; //This update is still null
            }
        }
        if (currentAdmin == null) {
            throw new InexistentUserException("The admin does not exist");
        }
        return currentAdmin;
    }
    
    public Admin(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

### Edit - a version with while to be more efficient

```
package eu.webfarmr;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Admin {
    private String username;
    private final static Admin[] adminList = new Admin[] {new Admin("Alice"), new Admin("Bob"), new Admin("Carol") };
    
    public static Admin getAdminByName(String name) throws InexistentUserException {

        Admin currentAdmin = null;
        boolean found = false;
        Iterator<Admin> iterator = Arrays.asList(adminList).iterator();
        while(!found && iterator.hasNext()) {
            Admin admin = iterator.next();
            found = admin.getUserName().equals(name);
            if (found){
                currentAdmin = admin;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            throw new InexistentUserException("The admin does not exist");
        }
        return currentAdmin;
    }
    
    public Admin(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved, thanks for the help. Exception taken out of the loop, removed the local variable currentAdmin and returned the admin in the loop.

Comment: Unless OP is specifically looking for the last match, the simplest implementation would be `for (Admin admin : adminList) if (admin.getUserName().equals(name)) return admin; throw new InexistentUserException();`

Comment: true but I hate breaking out of a for loop with a return statement but that is indeed the shortest path

Answer (score 1):

if you are using java 8 or above, you might consider using java streams to solve this.
https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Streams will let you iterate through elements and filter based on an objects field, which in this case would be the Admins name. Note that it assumes that each admin has a unique name.

An example related to your problem:

(If adminList is a java.util.List)
'''
public static Admin getAdminByName(String name) throws Exception
{

```
    return adminList.stream()
    .filter(admin -> admin.getUserName().equals(name))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Admin  " + name + " does not exist"));
}
```

'''

If the adminList is an array, try:

'''
public static Admin getAdminByName(String name) throws Exception
{

```
    return Arrays.stream(adminList)
    .filter(admin -> admin.getUserName().equals(name))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Admin " + name +" does not exist"));
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

at the first iteration of for loop if the condition becomes false then exception will be thrown and null will return.
You need to change your throwing section of your code and put it at the end of for loop and check if it didn't find and its null then throw the exception:

```
public Admin getAdminByName(String name) throws InexistentUserException {
    Admin currentAdmin = null;
    for (Admin admin : adminList) {
        if (admin.getUserName().equals(name)) {
            currentAdmin = admin; // This update is still null
            break;
        }
    }
    if(currentAdmin == null) {
        throw new InexistentUserException("The admin does not exist");
    }
    return currentAdmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like that

```
public Admin getAdminByName(String name) throws InexistentUserException {

    boolean found = false;

    Admin currentAdmin = null;
    for (Admin admin : adminList) {
        if (admin.getUserName().equals(name)) {
            currentAdmin = admin;
            found = true; // This update is still null
        }

    }
    if (found) {
        return currentAdmin;
    } else {
        throw new InexistentUserException("The admin does not exist");
    }
}
```